# SwiftUI - ScrollView not scrolling all the way to the bottom

Tags: scrollview, swiftui, geometryreader

I having problems with getting my scroll view to scroll all the way to the bottom. What's odd is that when it's populated with one set of data, it doesn't have this issue, however, in the other data set it gets to the last item and I can't scroll to the see the bottom half of the HStack.

[image]

Here's the code for the view

```
import SwiftUI

struct FestivalDescription: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

var passportTitle: String
var passportImageVert: String
var venues: [Venue]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack{
                    if geometry.frame(in: .global).minY <= 0 {
                        Image(self.passportImageVert)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            .offset(y: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY/9)
                            .clipped()
                    } else {
                        Image(self.passportImageVert)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height + geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Image("script_passport")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.75)
                        Text(self.passportTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .padding(.top, 10)

                        // Insert Navigation Link

                        NavigationLink(destination: FestivalDetails(passportTitle: self.passportTitle, venues: self.venues, venueProd: [])) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("View all Food & Drinks")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .padding()
                            }.frame(width: 210, height: 50)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(4)
                                .padding(.top, 8)
                        }
                        // End Button
                    }
                }
            }.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.63)
                .clipped()// Ends GeometryReader
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Festival Booths")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.top, 24)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                ForEach(self.venues) { venue in
                    NavigationLink(destination: VenueDetails(title: venue.title,  venueImage: venue.venueImage, venueDesc: venue.venueDesc, venueArea: venue.venueArea, venueLat: venue.venueLat, venueLong: venue.venueLong, venueProd: venue.venueItems)) {
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Image(venue.venueImage)
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 366, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 300)
                                    .scaledToFill()

                                HStack {
                                    Text(venue.title)
                                        .font(.body)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                                    Text(venue.venueDesc)
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("bodyText"))
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                        .lineLimit(2)
                                        .frame(height: 40)
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }.padding(.bottom, 16)
                }
                // End VStack of Venues
               // Spacer()
            }.padding(.horizontal, 24)
            .background(Color("bodyBackground"))

            // Ends Bottom Layer VStack
        }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) // Ends ScrollView
        .background(Color("bodyBackground"))

        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {

                    VStack {
                        Text("")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 120)
                            .background(Color("navBackground"))
                            .opacity(0.3                     )
                        Spacer()
                    }

                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) // Ends ZStack
            } // Ends Geometry Reader
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { gr in
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                 .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))
                                .padding(.leading, 16)
                            HStack {
                                Text("Passports · Passport Details")
                                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                     .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))

                                    .padding()
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }.frame(width: gr.size.width * 0.92, height: 48)
                            .background(Color("navBackground"))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                        .shadow(color: Color("Shadow"), radius: 10, x: 2, y: 7)
                    }.padding(.leading, 16)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 50)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } // Ends Floating Menu ZStack

    } // Ends Main ZStack
} 

}
```

Comment: Well, actually, this code is not readable - try to break it apart on several subviews, but I assume the issue is due to those many hardcoded values in padding, size, height, etc.

Answer (score 4):

For my codebase, if you put GeometryReader outside ScrollView then my ScrollView will scroll to the bottom.

```
GeometryReader { 
    ScrollView {
        //...stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue was with the aspect ratio modifier on my image. I set it to fit instead of fill and that fixed the issue.