# ScrollView Reader not scrolling all the way to the bottom of the list

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I read about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469298/swiftui-scrollview-not-scrolling-all-the-way-to-the-bottom), it didn't work. I tried adding the `.id()` to the MessageView but it didn't work either. Also the message model implements the Identifiable protocol

```
@ViewBuilder
    func MessagesView() -> some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
            List(viewModel.messages) { message in
                MessageView(message: message)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .background(Color.black)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .onChange(of: viewModel.messages) { _ in                    
                withAnimation {
                    scrollReader.scrollTo(viewModel.messages.last, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I fix it? it scrolls automatically but the scroll ends at the middle of the last cell. So it looks cropped, you need to manually scroll all the way to the bottom

Comment: `viewModel.messages.last` won't be changed yet. Use the parameter you're ignoring in the `onChange` callback -- eg `.onChange(of: viewModel.messages) { newValue in` and scroll to `newValue.last`. May need to use `Task { @MainActor` as well to jump to the next run loop.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, I understand your point but still, the scroll doesn't go all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewBuilder
    func MessagesView() -> some View {
        
        let lastId = "last"
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
            List(viewModel.messages) { message in
                MessageView(message: message)

            Color.clear
                .frame(height: 100)
                .id(lastId)

            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .background(Color.black)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .onChange(of: viewModel.messages) { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    scrollReader.scrollTo(lastId, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You could just add another view below your messageViews and have it scroll to that.